# Why does prototype's constructor refer back to itself?

Tags: javascript

From [Mozilla-javascript-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

"*Each object has a private property which holds a link to another object called its prototype. That prototype object has a prototype of its own, and so on until an object is reached with null as its prototype. By definition, null has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain.*"

**First question** - I hope by "each object contains the **prototype**", the author meant "each function object" contains the *public* **prototype** property, because an object like this `var myObj = {}` doesn't have any *public* prototype.

Please see the concole screenshot below - notice how public prototype property(and not the private `__proto__`) doesn't exist for an object created with {}  -
[image]

**Second question** - After reading the above-mentioned literature when I checked the prototype chain of a simple function, at first it seemed to be going infinitely deep - but then I realized that the constructor of the prototype is actually referring back to itself.  Unlike how it is mentioned in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) - the prototype chain here seems to be not getting ended with `null` as the root.

I imagine this was designed to support the prototype based inheritance. But I would appreciate if it could be explained, ***exactly how this self-reference in the prototype's constructor helps in achieving that***?

[image]

Comment: Regarding "an object like this `var myObj = {}` doesn't have any prototype", that object would have `Object.prototype` as its prototype.

Comment: @Seb .. see the edit on my first question.  
  var someObject = {};  
someObject.prototype.someOtherProperty = "SomeString";  
throws "prototype not defined" exception

Comment: In order to access _instance_ prototype, you have to use `Object.getOwnPrototype(someObject).someOtherProperty` or in devtools (I think it's not recommended in actual code) `someObject.__proto__.someOtherProperty` or just `someObject.someOtherProperty`. `prototype` is a property of `class`, not its instance. Instance is still linked to prototype but can be accessed differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to look up the prototype chain described there:

> Each object has a private property which holds a link to another object called its prototype. That prototype object has a prototype of its own, and so on until an object is reached with null as its prototype. By definition, null has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain.

You should look at the `__proto__` properties (which will point to the *internal prototype* of the object being examined).

[image]

Here, you see that the internal prototype of `myFunctionObj` is `Function.prototype`, and going up the next level of `__proto__` takes you to `Object.prototype`, which has no `__proto__` (the end of the prototype chain).

The `prototype` property of `myFunctionObj` refers to the internal prototype of *instantiated objects* (like `const obj = new myFunctionObj();`, and then `obj.__proto__ === myFunctionObj.prototype`), not to the internal prototype of the `myFunctionObj` itself.

Only `function`s have a `.prototype` property, usually, and their `.prototype` will refer to the *internal prototype* of instances created with `new`. Plain objects don't have a `.prototype` property (because plain objects can't be called to instantiate something), but you can still access the internal prototype of a plain object (or of anything) using `Object.getPrototypeOf` (or `.__proto__`):

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(
  obj.__proto__ === Object.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype,
);
```

A function's `.prototype.constructor` is indeed just a self-reference back to the function.

```js
function foo(){};
console.log(
  foo.prototype.constructor === foo
);
```

It's not very useful when you already have a reference to the constructor, but it *is* useful when you have a reference to an instance, but don't know its constructor - with prototypal inheritence, accessing the instance's `.constructor` property will give you the function used to construct it:

```js
const bar = (() => {
  function Bar(){}
  const bar = new Bar();
  return bar;
})();

// now Bar is out of scope
// but you can still reference it because you have an instance:
const Bar = bar.constructor;
console.log(Bar);
```

Comment: "A function's .prototype.constructor is indeed just a self-reference back to the function." -- Why is it designed like that? that was the 2nd question..

Comment: @Tintin Because objects created using that function as a constructor get that prototype, and it makes sense for `obj.constructor` to be a reference to the constructor that was used to create it.

Comment: @Tintin The `.constructor` property is not useful when you already have a reference to the constructor, of course, but it can be useful for *instances* to be able to reference it, when you don't already know.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance.  One question - 
"Only functions have a .prototype property, usually," ... Please could you explain "usually" - ?

Comment: @Tintin Objects can be arbitrary key-value pairs, so one may assign a `prototype` property to an object which is *not* a `function`. It would be very confusing, but it's permitted. `const obj = { prototype: { foo: 'foo' }}`, or `myObj.prototype = {};`. It's legal, but almost any code that looks like that likely deserves refactoring. 99% of the time, when you see `<something>`.prototype, the `something` is a function, and the `.prototype` will be the internal prototype (the `__proto__`) of anything instantiated with that function.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question:

> That prototype object has a prototype of its own...

I think it's way easier to understand this concept if you actually look at a simple example of multiple levels of prototype and how it works in practice:

```
function ClassA() {
  this.a = 1;
}
ClassA.prototype.getA = function(){
  return this.a;
};

function ClassB() {
  this.b = 2
}
ClassB.prototype = new ClassA();
ClassB.prototype.getB = function(){
  return this.b;
};

var b = new ClassB();
console.log(b.getA());
> 1
console.log(b.getB());
> 2
```

Now you'll notice that as we're defining the class (a function), we extend (or add) a `prototype`. But when we look at an instance of the class (`b` in my example), there isn't a `prototype`; it's called `__proto__` as @CertainPerformance already explained). So looking at the prototype chain of `b`, you'll see this:

```
b.__proto__
> ClassA {a: 1, getB: ƒ}
b.__proto__.__proto__
> {getA: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
b.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
> {constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
b.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
> null
```

So when you type `b.getB()`, the JavaScript engine first looks at the direct properties in the `b` object, and sees no `getB`. Then it looks at `b.__proto__`, and finds it, and it's done.

For `b.getA()`, it does the same thing, but doesn't find it in the first prototype. So it continues to `b.__proto__.__proto__`, and finds it there.

What you're seeing is different. You're first looking at the `prototype` of a function, and seeing that it has another function called `constructor` inside of it. And since `constructor` is also a function, it has a `prototype` inside of it. And so on, forever. But **that** is the prototype of the constructor function, **NOT** a part of the prototype chain of the original function/object.